# How to check if user is authenticated in React with express sessions and apollo on backend?

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, apollo-server, express-session

I have an app where I want to authenticate a user and show authenticated user pages which are unavailable to a non authenticated one`enter code here`.

On backend I am using express-sessions and apollo-server.

Basically my idea was to set userId in the session, then check if it is empty or not and send from backend to frontend if user is authenticated or not.

My index.ts file is as following:

```
const { createClient } = require('redis');
let redisClient = createClient({ legacyMode: true });

async function main() {
  const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

  // check if userid exists 
  function isAuthenticated(req: any) {
    const userId: string = req?.userId;

    return !!userId;
  }

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    plugins: [ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer })],
  });

  await server.start();

  await redisClient.connect();

  app.use(
    bodyParser.json(),
    cors<cors.CorsRequest>(),
    session({
      store: new RedisStore({
        host: host,
        port: 6379,
        client: redisClient,
      }),
      secret: process.env.SECRET,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      },
    }),
    expressMiddleware(server, {
      context: async ({ req, res }) => {
        return { req, res, isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated(req) };
      },
    })
  );

  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_DB_URI || '');
    console.log(`Mongoose connected on port`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  await new Promise<void>((resolve) =>
    httpServer.listen({ port: 4000 }, resolve)
  );
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000/`);
}

main();
```

my sign-in resolver is this:

```
signInUser: async (_, { user }, context) => {
      const { username, password } = user;
      const foundUser = await UserModel.findOne({ username });
      if (foundUser) {
        const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, foundUser.password);

        if (match) {
          if (context.req.session) {

            context.req.session.userId = foundUser.id; // here I am setting user id to the session

            return { message: 'Signed in successfully!', status: 'success' };
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

and

```
Query: {
    isAuthenticated: (_, __, {isAuthenticated}) => {
      return isAuthenticated;
    },
  },
```

And on frontend I created a hook like this, to use in my components.

```
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client';

export const IS_AUTHENTICATED = gql`
  query IsAuthenticated {
    isAuthenticated
  }
`;

const useAuth = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery(IS_AUTHENTICATED);

  return {
    isAuthenticated: data && data.isAuthenticated,
  };
};

export default useAuth;
```

The problem is that I `req` which I check `userId` does not have a `userId` yet in the apollo context. So it is always false. So I am not sure what approach  would be better there?

I don't really want to set the cookie as  `httpOnly: false` and manipulate it on frontend, for example.